# Return interface or class

Tags: c#, interfaces, class

Suppose I have a method

```
public List<User> GetBatchOfUsers(IEnumerable<int> userIDs)
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    // some database stuff

    return users;
}
```

I have read that it would be better to return an interface (either `IList` or `IEnumerable`) as opposed to returning a `List`.  Some arguments I have heard for doing so is that it hides data, and gives the API developer the flexibility of changing the internal representation of the data at a later date.

My concern about just returning an `IEnumerable` is that you lose functionality, such as random access and the `Count` property.

I know that accepting an `IEnumerable` as a parameter makes sense, as it gives the consumer the best flexibility to send data to my method, the minimalist set of requirements for the method to operate.

What is the best practice for the return type?

Comment: Far more important: take an interface as parameter type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally speaking, you may start with interfaces, and only move to put the concrete type as the return type if you find that you use the extra methods more frequently than expected.

Well, if you return an interface, you retain more flexibility. You can change the implementation later to return a different concrete type. On the other hand, it obviously gives the caller less information, so they may not be able to perform certain operations. (For example: if you return `List<T>`, the caller can use ConvertAll etc... which they can't if you only declare that you return `IList<T>`.) In some situations it's worth specifying the concrete type.

Regarding Count or Sort method, there is no standard collection interfaces for that . However, you could write an extension method to sort or count any IList.

Comment: I guess this isn't really a hard rule then?

Comment: yes, it really depends on usage.

Answer (score 1):

If You need your collection to have a `Count` you can use `ICollection<T>`, which is general enough.

Comment: -1. Count was already discussed and this answer adds nothing new

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, this is not an answer, its a comment.

Comment: @superM It’s valuable enough to merit its own answer, I think, since it explicitly addresses OP’s reason for deciding against interfaces in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You return what is prudent for the method you're defining. Is what you're doing returning a series of items (the focus is on the items), or is it returning a collection of items (the focus is on the collection as a whole)? Is it worthwhile to allow variance in the implementation of the collection? If it will never make sense to use a generator or `HashSet` then just use the `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Specific to the example method: You're right that returning `IEnmuerable<T>` would mean you would lose the functionality of `Count` and indexing (although you could use LINQ methods `Count()` and `ElementAt()`, which are implemented efficiently if the type they're used on actually implements `IList<T>`).

If you returned `IList<T>`, you would lose some functionality, but the gain in generality is probably worth it.

But even better would be something between `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>`, because it most likely doesn't make sense for the consumer to mutate the returned collection, but it does make sense for him to use `Count` or indexing.

In .Net 4.5, there is such interface: [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `IReadOnlyList` sounds good when I can get VS2013, thanks!